# How to clear all previous back-stack of Activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to clear all previous activity stack and launch new activity. But when i press back key control goes to previous activity. I am not finished all previous activity. When i logout i want to exit from app.
I used below flags:

```
intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and added below lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

But there is white screen appears before launching new activity.

I also changed theme to Translucent but while launching activity, but it shows android home icons for some moment.

I don't want to use:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

just set this flag in intent,

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: White screen appears again.

Comment: this flag clear your previous all activity and start new activity.

but can't get your point.

Comment: I agree with you all previous activity removed. but while launching new there is white screen appears for a moment and then new activity visible to user.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you

```
 logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Activity",
                            MODE_PRIVATE);

                    /*AppState.getSingleInstance().setLoggingOut(true);*/
                    setLoginState(true);
                    Log.d(TAG, "log out and go to first activity");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this,
                            LoginPage.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  /*  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |   
                                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);*/
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish() // finish this activity 

                }
            });
```

Comment: White screen not appeared, but previous activity stack is not removed. On key back previous activity resumed that i haven't finished.